# Как сделать так, чтобы все дети одного контейнера накладывались друг на друга?

Tags: html, css

В контейнер помещены несколько *div*-ов.

Как сделать так, чтобы они все накладывались друг на друга, применив стиль только на этом контейнере?

А если так нельзя, то как можно?

Comment: `.container { position: relative;} .container div { position: absolute;}`

Comment: @Deonis: неа...  А если написать absolute, то у детей все стили сбрасываются. У детей позиция не установлена. Только ширина и высота.

Comment: Может попробуете более подробно описать результат, который хотели бы получить? В конце концов, скрин сделайте.

Comment: что значит все сбрасываются ? "сбрасывается" только position :)

Comment: @Deonis: ну я написал что хочу, чтобы дети накладывались друг на друга. Могу лишь более подробно объяснить значение слова накладывались. Вот представьте что у Вас есть изображение моря и изображение лодки. И мне нужно НАЛОЖИТЬ лодку НА море, а не ПОД море.

Comment: @Deonis: спасибо! Вы правильно подсказали, это я не увидел .container div

Comment: Распределите по слоям с помощью свойства `z-index`. [Пример в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/hndtc66h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну если я правильно все понял то примерно так 
html для примера

```
<section>
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</section>
```

css

```
section{
  position:relative;
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;}
section div{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;}
section div:first-child{
  top:0;
  left:0;}
section div:last-child{
  top:0;
  left:0;}
section div:nth-child(2){
  top:0;
  left:0;}
section div:nth-child(3){
  top:0;
  left:0;}
```

и если используете картинки используйте png c прозрачностью. Это то что вы имели в виду или нет ?